# How do I keep the keyboard hidden when it's not wanted?

Tags: iphone, xcode, keyboard

The app I'm working on allows the user both to read text and to compose text, using different buttons.  My problem now is that on the screen for reading text, if the user taps inside the UITextView box used on the screen for writing text, the keyboard appears.  The UITextView in this case is `self.textView`; I've put the keyboard notifications and the keyboardWillShow method inside `if(self.textView)` statements and then made sure to call `[self.textView removeFromSuperView]` and set `self.textView = nil;` at the beginning of the reading text methods, but the keyboard still appears when you tap the space where `self.textView` is set (programmatically, by the way, not using the IB).

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**  Thanks for the answers, guys and gals, but still that darn keyboard keeps coming back, just like the cat in the song....  Here's my code.  Forgive its length, please, if you can; if I've done something wonky I don't know where it is, and so I don't know what to leave out.

Here's `viewDidLoad`.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.textView.editable=NO;
self.textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(previousHaiku)];
swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(nextHaiku)];
swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
 NSError *error;
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gayHaiku.plist"];
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
 {
 NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gayHaiku" ofType:@"plist"];
 [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
 }
 self.gayHaiku = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
 [self nextHaiku];
}
```

Here's `nextHaiku`, the last method called in `viewDidLoad` -- this is the reading method.

```
-(void)nextHaiku
{
[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
[self.bar removeFromSuperview];
self.textToSave=@"";
self.haiku_text.text=@"";
[self.view viewWithTag:1].hidden = NO;
[self.view viewWithTag:3].hidden = NO;
int indexOfHaiku;
NSMutableArray *arrayOfHaikuSeen;
NSString *cat;
if (!self.selectedCategory) cat = @"Derfner";
else cat = self.selectedCategory;
NSArray *filteredArray;
if (cat==@"all")
{
    filteredArray = self.gayHaiku;
    indexOfHaiku = self.indxAll;
    arrayOfHaikuSeen = self.theseAreDoneAll;
}
else
{
    indexOfHaiku = (cat==@"user")?self.indxU:self.indxD;
    arrayOfHaikuSeen = (cat==@"user")?self.theseAreDoneU:self.theseAreDoneD;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == %@", cat];
    filteredArray = [self.gayHaiku filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
int array_tot = [filteredArray count];
int sortingHat;
NSString *txt;
if (array_tot > 0)
{
    if (indexOfHaiku == arrayOfHaikuSeen.count)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            sortingHat = (arc4random() % array_tot);
            if (![arrayOfHaikuSeen containsObject:[filteredArray objectAtIndex:sortingHat]]) break;
        }
        txt = [[filteredArray objectAtIndex:sortingHat] valueForKey:@"quote"];
        if (!arrayOfHaikuSeen || arrayOfHaikuSeen.count==array_tot)
        {
            arrayOfHaikuSeen = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [arrayOfHaikuSeen addObject:[filteredArray objectAtIndex:sortingHat]];
        indexOfHaiku = arrayOfHaikuSeen.count;
        if (arrayOfHaikuSeen.count==filteredArray.count)
        {
            [arrayOfHaikuSeen removeAllObjects];
            indexOfHaiku=0;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        txt = [[arrayOfHaikuSeen objectAtIndex:indexOfHaiku] valueForKey:@"quote"];
        indexOfHaiku += 1;
    }
}
//Need to test to make sure it starts over once all 110 haiku have been seen.

CGSize dimensions = CGSizeMake(320, 400);
CGSize xySize = [txt sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0] constrainedToSize:dimensions lineBreakMode:0];
self.haiku_text = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((320/2)-(xySize.width/2),200,320,200)];
self.haiku_text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14];
self.haiku_text.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.haiku_text.text=txt;
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.25;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.view addSubview:self.haiku_text];

if (cat==@"user")
{
    self.theseAreDoneU = arrayOfHaikuSeen;
    self.indxU = indexOfHaiku;
}
else if (cat==@"all")
{
    self.theseAreDoneAll = arrayOfHaikuSeen;
    self.indxAll = indexOfHaiku;
}
else 
{
    self.theseAreDoneD = arrayOfHaikuSeen;
    self.indxD = indexOfHaiku;
}
}
```

And here's the writing method.

```
-(void)userWritesHaiku

//Set up the screen.
[self clearScreen];
self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, 280, 150)];
self.textView.delegate = self;
self.textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
self.textView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14];
self.textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.textView.editable=YES;
self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:217 green:147 blue:182 alpha:.5];
[self.view addSubview: self.textView];

[self loadNavBar:@"Compose"];
[self addLeftButton:@"Instructions" callingMethod:@"haikuInstructions"];

//If you've added text before calling haikuInstructions, when you return from haikuInstructions the textView window with the different background color AND the keyboard.
[self addRightButton:@"Done" callingMethod:@"userFinishedWritingHaiku"];
self.titulus.hidesBackButton=YES;
[self seeNavBar];

//Create and add the space for user to write.
[self createSpaceToWrite];
if (self.textToSave!=@"")
{
    self.textView.text = self.textToSave;
}
[self.view addSubview:self.textView];
[self.textView becomeFirstResponder];

//Keyboard notifications.

if (self.textView)
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

}

Comment: can you describe more about button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out that the whole time there was a `UITextView` I'd created in the xib and forgotten about because it was hiding under the main view--when I decided to create the `UITextView` programmatically I didn't remember to delete the other one, because I couldn't see it, but it was there working its evil will the entire time.  I finally figured this out after commenting out literally the entire code with the exception of `[super viewDidLoad]` and removing everything from the xib.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
[self.textView setEditable:NO];
```

Comment: Drat--that doesn't seem to do anything either.  I've posted my code above in an edit to the question--maybe I've done something weird and messed up without realizing it (that would certainly be a first...).

Answer (score 1):

When the user taps on the reading button, I would just call

```
self.textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

and when you want them to edit it call

```
self.textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Sorry, I looked at the docs and its the editable property you want to set for that one. self.textView.editable = NO; for example. Heres the link to the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to do the trick, either.  I've edited my question just in case I've done something wonky somewhere else....

Comment: @Joel Derfner when you first run the app, are the previous entries there on screen? If so, is it editable at that time?

Comment: The entries aren't there on the screen to begin with--only an editable text view and the keyboard, though I can make it so that the keyboard only appears after the user taps in the text view.  I'm beginning to suspect a weird bug that's just hiding very, very effectively....